# "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed" message

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

"**This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed**" message when try to add/edit every tag wiki from yesterday.

What is the issue? and how can I fix it? You can see message in below screenshot.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Well...the post was deleted, so you can't add new content or edit existing content.  It's tough to say what the "issue" is, since I imagine that's behaving as designed.  What specific problems were you running into, and in reference to what post?

Comment: I am trying to edit tags. see this http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/108063 link is giving message

Comment: Could the tag have been automatically deleted yesterday, then resurrected ~6 hours ago?

Comment: But this message is coming for every tags i am going to edit

Comment: Well, you didn't specify *that*.  I'm not entirely sure what could be going on there without digging a bit deeper.  Have you had any of your tag suggested edits rejected?

Comment: Add a screenshot of the message. Also, are you editing via browser, mobile app or mobile web?

Comment: @BhumiShah Could you please update the question stating that it happens on every tag? Could you also elaborate a little bit, perhaps with a screenshot on what is going on on your side? In this state, the question is not very useful nor easy to grasp.

Comment: find attached screenshot above

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you doing anything “unusual” (HTTPS, proxy, extension, userscript, blocking cookies, …)?

Comment: no,It's not working in any browser,so not a browser issue

Comment: I know it is a kind of bun. When the bun will disappear?

Answer (score 5):

You suggested about 50 tag edits on November 7th, many of which were (correctly!) rejected as inappropriate. As a result, you have been blocked from suggesting edits for some time.

For instance, [you suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6176302) that the [multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidex) tag wiki have the content:

> The multidex classes will not be included in the classes.dex file (the first one read by the classloader), which in turn will render all this useless.

— which was copied from https://github.com/casidiablo/multidex

---

And [you suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6176081) that the [balana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balana) tag wiki have the content:

> alana has extension point called “ResourceFinderModule” where you can plug your own resource finders. These resource finders would help PDP to finding the child (or hierarchical) resources. In this sample, sample resource finder module has been implemented to cater the above requirement.

— which was copied from http://xacmlinfo.org/category/balana/

---

And [you suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6176287) that the [sones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sones) tag wiki have the content:

> Sones GraphDB was developed by the company sones in Erfurt and Leipzig.

— which was copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sones_GraphDB

---

**These are NOT appropriate edits.** You are copying content from external sources without attribution, and, in many cases, the content you are using is often not even relevant in the context of a tag wiki.

If you are not sure what a tag is about, leave its tag wiki alone — do not try to write a tag wiki "blind". If the tag is important enough, someone else with better knowledge of the subject will come forward to write it.

Additionally, **not all tags need wikis**. Most of the tags you have been creating wikis for have a very small number of questions tagged (often just one). Tags with very few questions tagged are automatically deleted after a period of inactivity; they do not need descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

Too many rejected edit suggestions

```
Bhumi Shah had 309 edit suggestions approved, and 70 edit suggestions rejected
```

Although I found this, the equation may be outdated?

"When deciding on whether we should ban or not, we now look at your last 7 days of activity.

```
 If (rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5, you will be auto-banned."
```

SOURCE: [Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days)

But in your case `If (70 - (309 / 3)) >= 5` You shouldn't have been, but like I said the equation could have changed as this was 3 years ago.

Comment: Then when i will get edit access?

Comment: I'm not sure, possibly 24/48 hours or 7 days? I'm sure a mod will leave a comment letting you know.

Comment: but it's blocked from last week

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review  go here, does it say "Too many of your edits were rejected."?

Comment: @Matt *last seven days* not over life time.

Comment: @Compass i know, thats why i said "When deciding on whether we should ban or not, we now look at your last 7 days of activity"